# How to accumulate the modifications made on a string in each one of the iterations of a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops, for-loop

```py
import re

input_text = "Acá festejaremos mi cumpleaños. Yo ya sabía que los naipes estaban abajo de su manga." #example 1

list_all_adverbs_of_place = ["aquí", "aqui", "acá" , "aca", "abajo", "bajo", "alrededor", "al rededor"]
place_reference = r"((?i:\w\s*)+)?" #capturing group for an alphanumeric string with upper or lower case

for place_adverb in list_all_adverbs_of_place:
    pattern = r"(" + place_adverb + r")\s+(?i:del|de)\s+" + place_reference + r"\s*(?:[.\n;,]|$)"

    input_text = re.sub(pattern, 
                        lambda m: f"((PL_ADVB='{m[2] or ''}'){m[1]})", 
                        input_text, re.IGNORECASE)

print(repr(input_text)) # --> OUTPUT
```

How to make the `input_text` variable not be reset in each iteration of the for loop, so that the changes made by the `re.sub()` function in one iteration are kept for the following iterations of the loop?

```py
"((PL_ADVB='')Acá) festejaremos mi cumpleaños. Yo ya sabía que los naipes estaban ((PL_ADVB='su manga')abajo)." #for example 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think `input_text` is being reset after each iteration? Your example seems to be working as it should. Actually, a loop is unnecessary here. You can build your pattern by joining the list elements with `|`:

```
import re

input_text = "Acá festejaremos mi cumpleaños. Yo ya sabía que los naipes estaban abajo de su manga." #example 1

list_all_adverbs_of_place = ["aquí", "aqui", "acá" , "aca", "abajo", "bajo", "alrededor", "al rededor"]
place_reference = r"((?i:\w\s*)+)?" #capturing group for an alphanumeric string with upper or lower case

pattern = re.compile(rf"({'|'.join(list_all_adverbs_of_place)})\s+(?i:del|de)\s+{place_reference}\s*(?:[.\n;,]|$)", re.IGNORECASE)

input_text = re.sub(pattern, 
                    r"((PL_ADVB='\2')\1)", 
                    input_text)

print(input_text)
```

Edit: `re.IGNORECASE` belongs in the pattern

Output:

```
Acá festejaremos mi cumpleaños. Yo ya sabía que los naipes estaban ((PL_ADVB='su manga')abajo)
```

Note: `Acá` is not captured because it is not followed be del/de.

Edit2: in order to get the desired result, all your groups could be capturing and you could check if #2 (ie. del/de) is empty in the lambda function:

```
pattern = re.compile(rf"({'|'.join(list_all_adverbs_of_place)})(\s+(?:del|de))?\s+{place_reference}\s*([.\n;,]|$)", re.IGNORECASE)

input_text = re.sub(pattern, 
                    lambda m: f"((PL_ADVB='{m[3]}'){m[1]}){m[4]}" if m[2] else f"((PL_ADVB=''){m[1]}) {m[3] + m[4]}", 
                    input_text)
```

Output:

```
((PL_ADVB='')Acá) festejaremos mi cumpleaños. Yo ya sabía que los naipes estaban ((PL_ADVB='su manga')abajo).
```